# Java inference : type variable with an upper bound that is an array type

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, jls

I have a question regarding the JLS 3rd edition, and the inference mechanism. It is stated in the section [15.12.2.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.7) that:

> If F = U[], where the type U involves Tj, then if A is an array type
>   V[], **or a type variable with an upper bound that is an array type V[]**

I tried to create a type variable with an array type upper bound, but this does not seem to be accepted by the compiler. Something like:

```
public class MyClass<T extends String []> { 
}
```

My question is: is the JLS wrong in this fragment, or did I miss something ? The last part of the sentence seems unsatisfiable for me.

Thanks

Comment: If anything is wrong it would be the compiler, not the JLS.

Comment: 3rd edition? Please provide a link to that quote.

Comment: The JLS is at least contradictory, as in the section 4.4, it is stated that:
Type variables have an optional bound,  T &  I 1 ...  I n . The bound consists of either a type variable, or a class or interface type T

Comment: Related [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6557960). I think the source of the confusion is that while you can't define an array type upper bound for a type variable, you can bind an array type to it via type inference.

Comment: Thanks biziclop. As this condition is not satisfiable at all, I guess I can simply ignore this fragment for my implementation of the inference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the details in the following bug:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6557960

The JLS is a bit incoherent, as it states in section 4.4:

> Type variables have an optional bound, T & I 1 ... I n . The bound
>   consists of either a type variable, or a class or interface type T

The type variable cannot have a bound that is an array type, which is contradictory with the part mentioned above in my question (from the section 15.12.2.7):

> or a type variable with an upper bound that is an array type V[]

This part can simply be ignored as it will never be satisfiable.

Many thanks biziclop for the link

Comment: The reference to array type upper bounds has been removed from the latest JLS too if I'm not mistaken.